# an error when I load a form the first time

Tags: php, forms, if-statement, get

When I load the page in the first time, it shows an error, how can I fix this?
-This is the error:

Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\Lynda.com\form_3.php on line 58
Please insert a USERNAME

```
<?php

$username=$_GET["username"];

if (empty($username)) {echo "Please insert a USERNAME";}
else{echo "Hello: ".$username;}

 ?>
```

Comment: This is line 58 : $username=$_GET["username"];

Answer (score 1):

You need to first check to see if `$_GET['username']` is defined:

```
if( isset($_GET['username']) && !empty($_GET['username']) {
    echo "Hello: " . $_GET['username'];
}
else {
    echo "Please insert a USERNAME";
}
...
```

If you wish to store it inside a variable, you can try:

```
if( isset($_GET['username'] ) {
    $username = $_GET['username'];

    if( !empty($username) ) {
        echo "Hello: " . $username;
    }
    else {
        echo "Please insert a USERNAME";
    }
}
```

...

Comment: @user2610218 No, in your code you are trying to use `$_GET['username']` before you have checked that it is set.

Comment: so you are saying I should not store it inside variable first?

Comment: @user2610218q Well, you haven't checked to see if there is anything to store inside the variable.